# AES Java encryption 16 byte key decryption with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography, aes

In my backend side they have created the encrypted message using AES algorithm with 16 byte key with this piece of code

Key: h7Ui63Mzqj61G87j

```
    public static String encrypt(String data, byte[] secretKey) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey(secretKey);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug(String.format("DataToEncrypt: %s, encryptedValue: %s", data, encryptedValue));
    }
    return encryptedValue;
}
```

But I am unable to decrypt the message with the same key using AES algorithm.

Comment: Your key is 16 characters long. How do you convert it into 32 bytes?

Comment: Ok, now we have 16 *characters* vs 16 *bytes*. How do you convert from characters to bytes?

Comment: And please show the Objective-C code you have so far. And tell us what "i cant able to decrypt message" means. Doesn't it compile? Does it crash? Does it produce the wrong output? What the input, what's the expected output and what's the effective output?

Comment: From the server side they encrypt the message with the key and in objective-c code can't decrypt the message with the same key

Comment: am getting null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this below link,

https://github.com/callmewhy/why-encrypt

Hope its help full.

Comment: Post the relevant info in case the link ever rots.

Comment: The referenced code uses ECB mode. Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.